# VS Code extension in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

I have been attempting to implement a simple VSCode extension in JavaScript for some time now.

I have completed the setup using yo code.
Then, I installed the necessary dependencies using npm install.
However, when I try to start a debug session by pressing F5, a new window appears.
During the debug session, I can see that my extension has started, I suppose.
But in the new window, I cannot find the "Hello World" command.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot find the "Hello World" command or that you cannot find the *output* of the "Hello World" command?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.